# One of two Help Center pages on flagging is incomplete and mostly redundant

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, privileges, help-center

The Help Center page [What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) attempts to explain flagging (In fact its path is `/help/flagging`.) It falls short of the goal, though:

> To flag a post that is neither spam nor offensive, select “it needs ♦ moderator attention” from the list and use the space provided to explain the issue. Questions have the additional option of being marked as off-topic or as a duplicate.

This isn't right: a low-quality answer or non-answer should be flagged as such, not with a moderator attention flag. But neither of these flags is mentioned anywhere on the page. Also, despite being aimed at new users, the page fails to mention that flagging is a 15 rep privilege.

On the other hand, the [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)  on flagging is nicely done, with screenshots and links for usage guides. But there is no link to it from `/help/flagging`.

Suggestion: remove most of `/help/flagging` page (except the first two paragraphs and the very last line), replacing it with a link to `/help/privileges/flag-posts`

Answer (score 4):

This page has become even more obsolete with the [changes to comment flagging (July 2017)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/336144)—comments may now only be flagged as rude or abusive; no longer needed or a custom reason. The current text is as follows:

> **Flagging a comment:**
>
> If the inappropriate content occurs in comment, hover over the offending comment and click the small flag icon that appears.
>
> You must specify a reason for each comment flag. The most common cases are listed in the comment flag dialog box:
>
> - rude or offensive
> - not constructive / off-topic — a comment that does not try to improve the post it appears on, or which introduces a topic unrelated to the question or answer
> - obsolete — a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been addressed by an edit to the post, clarified by additional comments, or contains no context because it references deleted content
> - too chatty — anything that's not relevant to the question or answer

The above is no longer true, as those options are no longer available to flaggers.

"Flagging a question or answer" is based on an older version of the flagging dialogue, and so is "Flagging a comment", so it seems that this corner of the Help Center could do with some love to make sure that it's accurate.

I agree with the proposal here that most of the flagging information should be deleted from this page and replaced with a link to the flagging privilege page, which has [already been updated nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298579/336144).

Answer (score 1):

I've updated this Help Center article. The two sections on flagging were collapsed into a single section that provides some core information. I don't want to take this section out completely, because I think it's important that folks at least get pointed the 'right way' if they encounter something problematic. But, I agree, having the authoritative information living in two places at once is a recipe for... well, if not disaster, at least out of date information.

So, it now contains *just* the information required to get someone a-flaggin', and then if they need more information, it points out to the flagging privilege page -- which will stay authoritative and up to date.