# Wasn't there a "not constructive" flag for comments?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I thought there was such a thing - and yes, I see that a handful of my comment flags are about "not constructive".

I wanted to use it just now - but the list of available flags only shows "rude", "obsolete", "moderator attention".

I *assume* that such changes are announced somewhere - so bonus question: where can one find a comprehensive list of such kind of "UI updates"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was announced in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/295232) by Shog9.

The answer to your bonus question: there is a list of [recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/295232), where it's also listed:

- 2017-07-14: Comments flag dialog has been redesigned, flag reasons changed/merged.

And there is also [What features did the Community Team discuss, have implemented, or have denied last month?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031) which lists the official timeline of features since January 2017.