# New UI for flagging comments to be updated in Flag Posts privilege page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-flags, privileges-page

Recently the UI changed for [flagging comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/312043). In the privileges page for the [Flag Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), the old UI image is still being used for the **Comment** section.

Can the new UI be displayed on all Stack Exchange site's **Flag Posts** privilege page.

> [image: New UI for flagging comments]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just made the change to the help center to include the new comment flag dialog. I also updated the [guide to comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) with the new dialog and categories.

Thanks for pointing it out.